# macOS did not apply new time zone settings

Tags: macos, timezone

I live in Turkey and recently Turkish government has opted out of Daylight Saving system, locking the country's time zone into UTC+3 permanently. If there wasn't this change in action, time should have been adjusted -1 hour into UTC+2 today midnight. But since the new regulation, there shouldn't have been taken any action by the OS and it should have stayed at UTC+3 (time shouldn't have changed at all). But it did on my Mac.

My iPhone didn't change time time (correct behaviour) and now it is 12:26 as I'm writing here in UTC+3. My Mac adjusted itself to UTC+2 and now it's 11:26 on my Mac (incorrect behavior).

I've updated the time settings (`sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com`), I'm sure that I'm in the right time zone:

[image]

Yet it's still at the incorrect time zone.

How can I fix this problem (without manually adjusting my Mac's timezone to some other country's with the UTC+3 timezone)?

Comment: I've got the same problem. There is no such awaiting time zone update.
Any clue about it? By the way I am not using sierra yet.

Comment: @ferhat do you have the latest updates (other than Sierra)? if yes, try restarting your computer if you didn't. latest update + restart fixed my issue, but again, I was on Sierra.

Comment: The real solution to this problem is to never vote for any government that would make a time zone change on less than 18 months' notice.

Comment: @MikeScott I don't wanna go off-topic, but do you really think that I voted for those murderers?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, there was an awaiting macOS update that I forgot about. I've applied the update, restarted, and the time zone corrected itself.